# What does $\langle X\rangle$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

My notes has the following.

Let $G$ be a group. Let $J = \{G_i\}_{i∈I}$ to be the collection of all subgroups of $G$ containing the subset $X ⊆ G$. We note that $G$ is nonempty, since $G$ itself contains $X$, and so $G$ is in $G$. This allows us to set $\langle X\rangle$ as follows: $$\langle X \rangle = \bigcap_{i∈I}G_i$$

My understanding is that $\langle X\rangle$ is all the subgroups of $G$ such that those subgroups all contain the elements of $X$. Is that true? Someone please explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle X\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $X$.  It is usually referred to as the subgroup generated by $X$.  It can also be defined as
$$\langle X\rangle=\{x_1^{a_1}\ldots x_n^{a_n}:x_k\in X,a_k\in\Bbb Z, 1\le k\le n\}. $$

Comment: Could you give an example please

Comment: Sure, let $G=(\Bbb C^*,\cdot)$, and $X=\{2,i\}$.  Then $\langle X\rangle=\{2^ni^k:n\in\Bbb Z, 0\le k\le 3\}$.  So $\langle X\rangle$ will have the elements $1, i, -1, -i, 2,2i,-2,2-i, \frac12,\frac12i,-\frac12,-\frac12i\ldots$.

Comment: I still don't understand... Where did you get $2^ni^k$ from? And why is $0 \leq k \leq 3$? And if $n \in \mathbb Z$, doesn't that mean there are infinite possibilities...

Comment: Yes, there are infinite possibilites.  Because $X=\{2,i\}$, $\langle X\rangle$ will consister of all powers of $2$, all powers of $i$ and all products of such elements.  Of course there are only 4 distinct powers of $i$, $i^0=1,i^1=i,i^2=-1$, and $i^3=-i$.  After that, the cycle repeats, $i^4=1$ etc.

Comment: Can you give a simple example, one that doesn't have infinite possibilities please. I really need to understand this fully.

Comment: What finite groups are you familiar with?

Comment: Multiplicitive groups like $C_2$ or $C_n$ in general. Or even better $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: Let $G=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, and let $X=\{2\}$.  Then $\langle X\rangle=\{0,2,4\}$.

Comment: doesn't every group have to have $1$?

Comment: In $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, the identity element is $0$.

Comment: OK let me try give an example. We have $G=\mathbb Z_5$ and $X=\{2\}$ so that means $\langle X \rangle = \{0,2 \}$???

Comment: Take $2$ and keep adding it. $2+2\equiv 4$, $2+2+2\equiv 1$, $2+2+2+2\equiv 3$, and $2+2+2+2+2\equiv 0$.

Comment: OK since the binary operation is addition in this, could you give an example of say $C_4$ please

Comment: I'm upvoting you for your amount of patience, :~).

Answer (score 4):

$\langle X \rangle$ is a subgroup, not a set of subgroups; in particular, it is the largest subgroup that is contained in every $G_i$. It is also called the subgroup *generated* by the set $X$, and is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains every element of $X$, as well as their products and inverses.

Comment: And to clarify your notes, $\langle X\rangle$ is also an intersection of every subgroup; of $G$ containing $X$. These are equivalent definitions.

Comment: @ElliotG I think the intersection of every subset of $G$ containing $X$ is $X$ itself; perhaps you mean subgroup?

Comment: Thanks; meant to say subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

This is the common notation and it means the subgroup generated by $X$. While the intersection of subgroups is a subgroup as well this is indeed the subgroup of $G$. Your definition is via "outer" approach: one can also define $<X>$ from "the inside" it consists of all expressions $\{x_1^{\varepsilon_1}...x_k^{\varepsilon_k}: x_j \in X, \varepsilon_k \in \{-1,1\}, k \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you seem to be misreading: each $G_i$ is a subset of $G$, and the intersection of a collection of subsets is also a subset.

Furthermore, each $G_i$ is a sub**group** of $G$, and the intersection of a collection of sub**groups** is also a sub**group**, so the right hand side $\cap_{i \in I} G_i$ is a sub**group**. So, by definition, $\langle X\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Furthermore, since each $G_i$ contains $X$, it follows that the subgroup $\cap_{i \in I}G_i$ contains $X$. So it is the smallest possible subgroup containing $X$, because it is contained in every other subgroup $G_i$ that contains $X$.